# Why is module.exports=router is needed?

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js server conf file, I set `app.use('/user', user.js)`, which maps `/user` route to a `user.js` file.

Then I create subrouting in my `user.js` file to handle my get or post requests.

My question is: what's the responsibility of `module.exports=router` at the end of this file?

If I remove it, routing stops working, so I don't understand if it is here to tell my server conf file that there are sub paths in `user.js`?

```
var express = require('express');

var user = require('../../models/user');
var db = require('../../models/index');


var router = express.Router();


router.get('/addUser',function (req, res, next) {
  db.user.create(req.body)
    .then(user => res.json({

      data: user,

    }))
    .catch(error => res.json({
      error: true,
      data: [],
      error: error
  }));
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
var user = require('../../models/user');
```

the `user` object would get whatever is being exported from the module in `user.js`. So in `user.js`, the `module.exports=router` is mapping a router and all logic that's required to map `/user` (along with the right callbacks etc...)

If you remove it, your `require` statement can't acquire an exported object from that module, which is why it would fail. Your user object will be nullified effectively.

Check out here for more info: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

Comment: @hbat I'd appreciate the green tick if you think this qualifies as the answer.

Comment: I thought `express.Router()` returned a singleton so exporting wasn't required.

Answer (score 2):

A router cannot listen(PORT) for requests on its own. The router is useful when you have lots of routes. It's useful for separating your app into multiple modules.

```
const app = express()
app.listen(port)
```

app is listening for the requests(not the Router) while your user.js is just a separate js file with some codes.

In `module.export` ,**module** is a variable that represents the current module and **export** is an object. Anything you assign to the `module.exports` will be expose as a module.

**copied: Module in Node.js is a simple or complex functionality organized in single or multiple JavaScript files which can be reused throughout the Node.js application.**

Once you do `module.export = Router` Now you have a newly created module. In nodeJs, you need to require a module before use it. `const user = require('./user.js')` will do that process. Once you require the node module into your app, you need to tell it to execute by `app.use('/' , user)`

**Or you can do something like below too**

in your user.js file,

```
var user = require('../../models/user');
var db = require('../../models/index');

module.export = (app) =>{
  app.get('/addUser',function (req, res, next) {
  db.user.create(req.body)
    .then(user => res.json({

      data: user,

    }))
    .catch(error => res.json({
      error: true,
      data: [],
      error: error
  }));
 });
}
```

in your main index.js,

```
const app = express()
require('./user.js')(app)
```